# Is there a "right way" to create skinny wars and an ear file in Gradle

Tags: war, ear, gradle

Using Gradle (and Java, obviously), I'd like to generate a skinny war (with no dependency jars in the war), and include all of the dependencies in the ear file.  I've done some digging, but I can't find any obvious "skinny war" tutorials for Gradle.

In Maven 2.2.1 (yeah, we're stuck in 2.2.1, don't ask me why), this was accomplished by [creating a separate ear project and repeating all of my dependencies from my sub-projects in the ear](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html).

I can imagine how I would duplicate this same hack in Gradle, but I'm hoping there's a smarter way to do this.  Does anyone have any ideas/examples/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the latest 1.0-M4 snapshot of gradle contains the new ear plugin. You can either update your wrapper configuration or download the snapshot directly from

http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/gradle-snapshots/gradle-1.0-milestone-4-20110610162713+0200-bin.zip

The complete distribution of this snapshot downloadable at  http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/gradle-snapshots/gradle-1.0-milestone-4-20110610162713+0200-all.zip contains a samples folder with two example usages of the newly introduced ear plugin.

Have a look at the example in samples/ear/earWithWar This example defines a ear with a war.

To get a skinny war, you have to modify the build.gradle of the war project. To get a war without thirdparty libs, you have to add the following snippet to samples/ear/earWithWar/war/build.gradle:

```
war{
    classpath = []
}
```

To get the thirdparty libs in the lib/ subfolder of your ear you have to add the lib used by the war plugin to the earlib configuration in the root project too. The example does this for the log4j library.

Now running "gradle ear" on the example project creates a ear with a skinny war and the thirdparty libs stored in the lib/ subfolder of the ear.

The complete snapshot contains further documentation in the docs/ subfolder about the ear plugin

Comment: Cool!  I read somewhere that an ear plugin might be in the works.  I'll get the new version as soon as I can (there's a process for that here at work, unfortunately), and check it out.

Comment: I've managed to try out the EAR plugin, and it's not working for me because I have a strange project structure left over from Maven (projects are in 'empty' sub-folders).  I'll circle back to this once I get a chance to fix our folder structure.  I guess I should also leave a note somewhere in the Gradle forums about how the plugin doesn't like extra folders in the project structure...

Comment: Okay, I've used the EAR plugin again, and it does work, but it seems to still lack support for "skinny wars".  Hopefully it'll get added as part of the milestone-4 final release...

Answer (score 1):

Setting `war { classpath = [] }` as suggested by Rene  prevents everything from being included - the final archive doesn't even contain  `WEB-INF/classes`. The only way I know of to exclude dependencies from a war file's `WEB-INF/lib` dir but stil include `WEB-INF/classes` is to use *providedCompile* and/or *providedRuntime* configurations. For example

`dependencies {
    providedCompile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')
}`

Comment: I solved this by adding this line: `war.classpath = war.classpath.filter { !it.name.endsWith('.jar') }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to get my hands on that snapshot build, but here's how I hacked things together since yesterday, just for the sake of completeness.  Please feel free to improve my Gradle/Groovy.  I'm sure it's not as elegant as it could be.

```
//Make sure the war and jars get built first
task ('ear', type:Jar, dependsOn: ":myWarProject:assemble" ){
    //This needs to be in the config block, or Gradle skips the task, assuming the file list for the jar/ear is empty...
    from{ "ear/src/main/application" }
}

ear.doFirst{
    //Set up the ear file name
    baseName = "myapp-" + rootVersion
    extension = "ear"

    //Gather up the jars required by all of the subprojects
    def allSubprojectDependencies = getAllProjectDependencies([
        "subproject1",
        "subproject2",
        "subproject3",
        "subproject4",
        "subproject5"
    ])
    from { allSubprojectDependencies }

    //grab the assembled war file
    from {
        subprojects.find{ it.name=="myWarFile" }.war.archivePath
    }

    //Other stuff required for our ear, such as security or eventing EJBs
    //Make sure you apply your "repositories" block to your root/ear project or "allProjects" if you do this...
    from { configurations.earConfig.files }

    //Create the classpath manifest
    manifestClassPath = allSubprojectDependencies.collect { it.name }.sort().join(' ')
    manifest { attributes( "Class-Path": manifestClassPath ) }
}

def getAllProjectDependencies (def projectNames){
    def allDependencies = []as Set
    projectNames.each{ projectName ->
        def subProject = subprojects.find{ subProject ->
            subProject.name.equals(projectName)
        }
        def subProjectDependencies = subProject.configurations.compile.files
        allDependencies.addAll subProjectDependencies
    }
    return allDependencies.unique{ a,b->
        if (a.equals(b)){
            return 0
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

(Please note, all jars are in the root of the ear on purpose.  Don't ask me why, but some people apparently like it that way.)